# <p:toggleSwitch> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: toggleSwitch

Tags: primefaces

when i try to use primeFaces toggleSwitch it shows an error as follows

***Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: toggleSwitch***

please suggest the correct library for **toggleSwitch**

Comment: You can see in the answer why you should always provide version info. Just a quick 'developer search' tip: if you'd searched for a generic error (e.g. leaving the toggleswitch out of the search) you'd have quickly found an answer to your problem. Cheers...

Comment: Even posting your title as is in google gave me results...which leads me to boldly ask if you actually did try searching based on the title?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably using a PrimeFaces version which is too old. `ToggleSwitch` was introduced in 7.0:

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/7.0/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/toggleswitch/ToggleSwitch.java

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/6_2/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/toggleswitch/ToggleSwitch.java